# Completely positive quantum channel

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

Let $\mathcal{E} \to CP(A \to B)$ (completely positive linear map) be a trace non-increasing $CP$ map.
Show that any operator sum representation $\{M_x\}_{x=1}^{m}$ of $\mathcal{E}$ satisfes $\sum_{x=1}^{m}M^{*}_xM_x  \leq I^A$.
Show that the marginal of the Choi matrix $J^{AB}{\mathcal{E}}$ satisfies $J^A{\mathcal{E}}:= Tr_B[J^{AB}_{\mathcal{E}}] \leq I^A$.

The proof the second part is as follows, but I dont know how to prove first part. Let$\mathcal{E}:\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}^A)\to \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}^B)$ be a linear map.  Clearly if $\mathcal{E}$ is completely positive then by  definition $J^{AB}{\mathcal{E}}:=\text{id} \otimes \mathcal{E}(\phi^{AA^{\prime}}_{+})\geq0$.

Suppose  now  that $J^{AB}_{\mathcal{E}} \geq 0$.   Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$,  and $|\psi^{RA}\rangle \in \mathbb{C}^k \otimes \mathbb{C}^d$, where R is a k-dimensional (reference) system.  $|\psi^{RA}\rangle = M_{\psi} \otimes I^A |\phi^{A A^{\prime}}_{+}\rangle$. Where $M_{\psi}:\mathcal{H}^{A^{\prime}} \to \mathcal{H}^R$is a linear operator.  We therefore have
$$ \text{id}_k \otimes \mathcal{E} |\psi^{RA}\rangle\langle\psi^{RA}| = (\text{id}_k \otimes \mathcal{E}) ( M_{\psi} \otimes I^A ) |\phi^{A A^{\prime}}_{+}\rangle \langle\phi^{A A^{\prime}}_{+}| ( M_{\psi}^{*} \otimes I^A ) $$
$$ = ( M_{\psi} \otimes I^A ) J^{AB}_{\mathcal{E}} ( M_{\psi}^{*} \otimes I^A ) $$
Finally  any  operator $\rho^{RA}\geq 0$  can  be  diagonalized  as $\rho^{RA}= \sum_{x=1}^m |\psi_x^{RA}\rangle \langle\psi_x^{RA}|$,  where $|\psi_x^{RA}\rangle \in  \mathbb{C}^k \otimes \mathbb{C}^d$ are  some  (possibly  unnormalized)  pure  states.   Since $|\psi^{RA}\rangle$ above  was arbitrary, we conclude that $(\text{id}_k \otimes \mathcal{E}) \rho^{RA} = \sum_{x=1}^m (\text{id}_k \otimes \mathcal{E}) (|\phi_x^{RA}\rangle \langle\phi_x^{RA}|) \geq 0$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is math question which should be asked in Mathstackexchange.

Comment: @FredericThomas Completely positive maps are very much about physics. Why else should one care about complete positivity?

Answer (score 1):

We are given $\mathcal{E}_{A\rightarrow B}$ to be some completely positive trace nonincreasing map with Kraus operators $\{M_i\}$ so that $\mathcal{E}(\rho) = \sum_i M_i\rho M_i^\dagger$.

For any $\rho$, it holds that
\begin{align}
\langle I_A, \rho\rangle &= \text{tr}(\rho)\\
&\geq \text{tr}(\mathcal{E}(\rho)) \\
&= \langle I_B, \mathcal{E}(\rho)\rangle \\
&= \langle I_B, \sum_i M_i \rho M_i^\dagger\rangle \\
&= \langle \sum_i M_i^\dagger M_i, \rho\rangle
\end{align}

Thus, $\langle I_A - \sum_i M_i^\dagger M_i, \rho\rangle \geq 0$ for any $\rho$ and hence, $\sum_i M^\dagger_i M_i \leq I_A$.

For the second question, let us choose an orthonormal basis $\{\vert i\rangle\}$ for $\mathcal{H}_A$. Note that $J(\mathcal{E}) = \sum_{i,j} \vert i\rangle\langle j\vert_A\otimes\mathcal{E}(\vert i\rangle\langle j\vert)_B$. Since $\mathcal{E}$ is trace nonincreasing, it holds that $\text{tr}(\mathcal{E}(\vert i\rangle\langle j\vert))\leq \text{tr}(\vert i\rangle\langle j\vert) = \delta_{ij}$ and hence

$$\text{tr}_B\left(J(\mathcal{E})\right) = \sum_{i,j} \vert i\rangle\langle j\vert_A\otimes\text{tr}\left(\mathcal{E}(\vert i\rangle\langle j\vert)\right)\leq \sum_{i,j}\vert i\rangle\langle j\vert \delta_{ij} = I_A $$

This proof, and other useful identities, can be found in these [lecture notes](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI-notes/TQI-notes.pdf) by John Watrous.